# Getting Object: "undefined" on React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am a newbie in react JS and I am trying to pull data from a url in Json format.
I did the following but I keep on getting a feeback at the console as

> Rovers: undefined.

How do I go about it when am supposed to get something like

> Rovers:[object, object, object]

```
class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state={rovers:[]};
 }
componentWillMount(){
  api.getRovers().then((response) =>{
   this.setState({
     rovers: response.rovers
   });
 });
}
render() {
  console.log("Rovers: ", this.state.rovers);
}
```

and this is where am calling the json link

```
var api={
  getRovers(){
   var url='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
   return fetch(url).then((response)=> response.json());
 }
};
module.exports=api;
```

Comment: How are you calling `render()`? It sounds like you're calling that before the API call finishes.

Comment: @krillgar Kindly advice on a better way to do it...I can't even tell the best way to

Answer (score 2):

The endpoint replies with object that does not include `rovers`. However, it includes : `id`, `userId`, `title` and `body`

---

[image]

---

That's why `response.rovers` is `undefined`. Then `this.state.rovers` is the same

#### So , you might mean `body` instead of `rovers` , in this case  , replace:

```
componentWillMount(){
  api.getRovers().then((response) =>{
   this.setState({
     rovers: response.rovers
   });
 });
}
```

By :

```
componentWillMount(){
  api.getRovers().then((response) =>{
   this.setState({
     rovers: response.body.split('\n')
   });
 });
}
```

Comment: Congrats  .. You are Welcome @wallraks